# Jenkins reports build shell syntax error but no error in bash

Tags: shell, jenkins

I want to read the value of an artifact ID in the *gradle.properties* file in the Jenkins (v. 2.17) build step 'Execute shell'.

The line to be read is something like this: `artifactId   = myArtifact`

The script command I use:

```
ARTIFACT_ID=$((grep -Po "(?<=^artifactId).*" gradle.properties) | tr -d '=' | tr -d ' ')
```

The jenkins job fails with this error:

> /tmp/hudson7118904411564834774.sh: 19: /tmp/hudson7118904411564834774.sh: Syntax error: Missing '))'

However, I can execute exactly this command line on the same build machine in the job's workspace directory with the proper user in the bash and I have no syntax error! Why doesn't it work in Jenkins?

I know that this line fails because of debug output before and after. There is no change directory command, ie. the script's working directory is still the job's workspace directory.

Comment: Why are you trying to run the `grep` in a sub-shell (which the grouping of the parentheses indicates you are trying to do)?  You simply don't need that inner set of parentheses.  Jens has explained why you get a syntax error; I'm not sure how the code ever works — it shouldn't by my reckoning (but I confess to only being a Bash user, not the Bash program).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one took me a while! Seems that the Jenkins shell doesn't like my brackets. This command works as expected:

```
ARTIFACT_ID=$( grep -Po "(?<=^artifactId).*" gradle.properties | tr -d '=' | tr -d ' ' )
```

Comment: There's no "Jenkins shell"; Jenkins uses the shell of your system.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `$((` is the start of *arithmetic expansion*, as used for `$((x + y))`, and it requires a terminating `))` token. If you want a subshell in a command substitution, use an extra space to avoid the tokens `$(` and `(` being combined:

```
ARTIFACT_ID=$( ( grep ... ) ... )
```

As Jonathan Leffler rightly observes, in your particular command, the subshell for `( grep )` is useless and can be eliminated.